# Why doesn't English employ an H in front of Ares?

Tags: vowels, greek, consonants, rules

While watching the movie *The Martian*, a question arose regarding the name *Ares*:

Greek Gods were metaphrased into Latin when Romans took over. **Ares** (from the Greek **Άρης**) was now named Mars, and so on. And, as such, NASA uses the name *Ares* for their mission to Mars.

[image: photo with a spacesuit from the movie; the word Ares spelled with no H is circled]

They also have a spacecraft named **Hermes**, an import of **Ερμής**. By this convention, shouldn't it be *Hares* then instead of *Ares*, since both start with a vowel, followed by a consonant (character "r")?

'**A**' might be an exception or something, yet, I remembered **Hagia Sophia** (in Constantinopolis), from the greek **Αγιά Σοφία**. This follows the same convention as *Hermes*, rather than that of *Ares*. Similarly, we have the name *Hades*.

Why is there variation in this convention?

Comment: Interestingly, Ngrams shows [a steadily declining usage of _Hares_](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hares%2Cares&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chares%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhares%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHares%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cares%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bares%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAres%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BARES%3B%2Cc0) until the two almost converge in present day.

Comment: @Cascabel That probably represents the dropping of soft Hs in English over time with a concomitant loss in spelling.  Or interference from rabbits.

Comment: There is also the issue that Ety shows nothing for "Hares"...

Comment: @Cascabel interesting indeed, but query also for "Hermes, Ermes", and you'll see that except from a spike, "Ermes" was almost never used.

Comment: I ran a query with a comparison [Hares, Ares](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=ares%2C+hares), and nothing for "Hares".

Comment: @DavidM LOL...I just got the rabbit reference. Almost all hits for "Hares" on Ngrams refer to the Bugs variety of  plural Hare.

Comment: This has nothing to do with English, which took the names more or less directly from Latin. From what I understand, the Greek letter epsilon was adapted from the Phoenician letter he, but used to represent the vowel sound; eta originally indicated the /h/ consonant, but also shifted to represent the vowel. Greek instead uses diacritics to mark /h/ ("rough breathing"). A rough breathing vowel got transliterated with an H into Latin, thus *Hera* and *Hermes* and *Helios*; smooth breathing vowels remained bare, thus *Ares* and *Apollo* and *Eos*.

Comment: Although I don't feel what you say as a Greek about how I pronounce these Greek names, you might have a point about the Latin element here @choster, and I think you could convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a transliteration of Greek to Latin, and not related to English.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the argument presented here makes no sense. Why would two completely different Greek letters (to my untrained eye) be transliterated if followed by an /r/?

Comment: @AzorAhai vowel and consonant was my motivation. :) Sorry if I am the cause of something that doesn't make you feel great. :/

Comment: I feel fine, I'm just confused.

Comment: @choster that's an answer not a closure reason: The OP didn't know how the words came from Greek to English, and common etymological information is  insufficient to give the necessary detail (I've checked)

Comment: You only have to go back about 40 years (before 1982) to reach a time when they were spelt differently in Greek as well. Ἄρης has smooth breathing (ψιλή), while Ἑρμῆς has rough breathing (δασεία). That’s the difference. Rough breathing was originally an /h/ sound, which is why that’s how it’s transliterated.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was born in 1992, but I've seen these rules, what you say makes so much sense - unfortunately, during the modern times, ψιλή and δασεία were sacrificed in the shrine of destructive wave of oversimplifying everything.

Comment: @gsamaras I think it’s perhaps a bit of a stretch to call it an _over_-simplification – after all, there hasn’t been a phonetic difference between, say, _ἡ_ (definite article, nominative singular feminine) and _ἤ_ (‘or’) for perhaps as much as 1,500 years, so it seems more fair to call still writing them differently an overcomplication of everything instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet from the perspective of this yes, I agree, but in a more general  way, it is, I believe, and an example can be seen in poems - but that's off topic now. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*Hermes* and *Ares* are reasonable representations in the Latin alphabet of the *sounds* of the Greek names. The /h/ sound is absent from classical Greek **spellings** of words which contained it (like *Hermes*) because the Attic Greek alphabet did not have a distinct character for it—the character ‹H› was used for eta ('long e', contrasting with epsilon, 'short e'). Starting in the Hellenistic period the presence or absence of /h/ was indicated by diacritic marks, the 'rough' and 'smooth breathing' signs.

The /h/ sound was subsequently lost in Greek.

Comment: You imply that the ancient Greeks pronounced **Ερμής** with a leading H, despite the spelling but you don't come out and say it directly. Perhaps you should do that.

Comment: Ερμής is mis-spelt in the original posting. In Classical Greek, all vowel-initial words are written with one of the breathing marks, either rough or smooth. so Ερμής should be Ἑρμής

Comment: @ColinFine It appears that OP is a (modern) Greek himself, so he naturally employs the modern spelling without the diacritic. ... And I'd be curious to know: did classical orthography employ the diacritics even in inscriptions and non-literary contexts, or were they more like the vowel points in Hebrew?

Comment: I'd like clarification. Is this what you're saying:
1. If an ancient Greek word begins with eta, that's transliterated as "he" regardless of aspiration.
2. If an ancient Greek word begins with alpha, that's transliterated "a" regardless of aspiration.
3. "Hagia Sophia" is exempt from this rule because it more recent than ancient times.

Comment: What's the difference between "Hades" and "Ares"?

Comment: @StoneyB Once the breathing marks were introduced and generalised (which happened gradually during Classical times – not sure exactly when, but I think in the Hellenistic period), they were quite commonly used in all contexts.

Comment: @Jetpack No, all Greek words that began with a rough breathing (/h/) are transliterated with an initial h, regardless of the following vowel; those that began with soft breathing (no /h/) are transliterated with nothing before the vowel. The difference between the initial sounds of _Ares_ and _Hermes_ existed **in Greek**:  ̓́Αρης has soft breathing,  ̔Ερμής and  ̔́Αγια Σοφία both have rough breathing.

Comment: (Typo: Ἑρμῆς, not Ἑρμής.)

Answer (score 4):

I’m afraid you are labouring under a misapprehension.  *Mars* is not the Latin for *Ares* with an aspirated first letter.  It is derived from the Oscan *Mavors*. He was the god of war, like Ares, but he was also supposed to be the father of Romulus and Remus.

Many of the stories about Ares and other Greek Gods were adopted into the Roman cannon.

But the names were not all the same.  So the Roman opposite number to *ΕΡΜΗΣ* was  not *HERMES*  but *MERCVRIVS (Mercury)* - the *V* representing a ‘u’ as in *put*.

Others have already pointed out that the initial epsilon of Greek *Ερμης* was aspirated:  Hence the imported H.

In modern Greek, vowels are not aspirated.  So what in ancient Greek would have been *Hodos Hermou (οδός Ερμού)* or Hermès Street is now pronounced *Odhos Ermou*  with no ‘h’ but an aspirated delta, pronounced as in ‘that’.

Comment: The OP is asking about _Ares_, not _Mars_.

Comment: The modern delta is not aspirated, it's lenited to a fricative.  (The fricatives θφχ are descended from true aspirates, but the terms are not interchangeable.)

Comment: @AntonSherwood True:  thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Like @StoneyB on hiatus suggested in the polytonic orthography of Ancient Greek there was the rough breathing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_breathing. The rough breathing comes from the left-hand half of the letter H.

https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%94%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%B1

Generally The sound that symbolized the rough breathing and its written performance was retained in words (see Homer-Homer, Ictor-Hector, Hypnosis-hypnosis) borrowed from Latin and other languages (either directly or indirectly from Latin).

In the Latin alphabet, as in the Attic dialect, it was rendered in writing with the letter H, from which, after all, the rough breathing derives. Specifically, the rough breathing symbol is a simplification of ├ (the left half of Ήτα).

Many words that in Ancient Greek had the rough breathing in English start with an H. e.g. ἱστορία -> history